# High availability RabbitMQ using gRPC as transport layer?

Tags: microservices, message-queue, rabbitmq, grpc

I have an idea to use gRPC for all microservices communication for the sake of simplicity.

Now there is a service that needs high availability, So the idea is to use RabitMQ as a message receiver from the outside.

Question: Do we still or possibly still preserve high availability by using gRPC as a transport layer for the message queue?

Comment: How gRPC and RabbitMQ contribute to the HA of the service? How do you define HA?

Comment: We see the message queue like rabbitMQ as a stable bucket that we can put anything we want. Whenever a consumer is down there still able to get up back to consume after whatever they have missed. That's the problem we want to solve.

Comment: That has nothing to do with HA. HA is about your service been up 24/7/365

Comment: However, We concern any message queue bucket availability rate will fall if we put gRPC in front.

Comment: Thought work. Have you made any proof of concept with the stack? You should, no matter what answer you get here. You should not make such an architectural decision only based on stranger's opinions.